# Custom Compass create project templates?

Tags: sass, compass-sass

When you use Compass to create a new project:

`$ compass create myproject`

It's creates the following predefined directory structure and files:

```
directory myproject/
directory myproject/sass/
directory myproject/stylesheets/
   create myproject/config.rb
   create myproject/sass/screen.scss
   create myproject/sass/print.scss
   create myproject/sass/ie.scss
   create myproject/stylesheets/print.css
   create myproject/stylesheets/ie.css
   create myproject/stylesheets/screen.css
```

So, that directory structure is pretty different than what I need. Is it possible to customize the directory structure and what files are created and what the content is of those files when creating new projects?

Comment: Did you try reading the documentation?  http://compass-style.org/install/

Comment: Of course. That page tells you how to create a new project, which creates the default template you see above. I'm trying to understand how to use your own custom directory structure template.

Comment: Did you skip over the part that says "Tell us about your project and we'll help you get it set up"?

Comment: Ah thank you. It was the `--bare` command I was looking for. Not sure why it didn't print that out originally. If you want to put in an answer below I'll give you credit. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure about nesting directories but changing the names of the default compass folders such as stylesheets, sass etc can be done with the following command

```
compass create testProject --bare --sass-dir "sass" --css-dir "stylesheets" --javascripts-dir "js" --images-dir "imgs"
```

Changing the text in the quotes for what you would like your directories to be named.